# Continuous deployment of WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a question regarding the WooCommerce continuous deployment. I need to update changes without effecting the user data, layout, and all other important data. Is there any way for continuous deployment without a break?
It will be a great help if someone can help.

Comment: There are many ways: First always use a child theme. You can include your code customizations in the functions.php file located in your child theme (same thing for the Css styles using style.css file). You can also use [Code snippet](https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets/) plugin for your code customizations, but you will need the child theme if you [override WooCommerce templates](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/). Now you should always **have a stage web site** to test your code, updates and other changes, before doing anything on the production site.

Answer (score 1):

Hello Asela and welcome to Stack Over Flow! I believe what are you looking for is the a staging environment. This mean that you want to test custom codes to your Woocommerce but not on the live website, or the website where your user's data are sored. Instead, you want to do your testing somewhere else, and when you are sure about them you updated the main site.

1- To do this you need a second WordPress install either on your hosting server or even on your local computer.

2- Place your custom codes into fucntion.php or inside a custom plugin.

3- When you are done testing, and you're satisfied with your customization you can simply upload your code into the main site.

This is my solution for you, please let me know if I'm didn't understand your goal, you can comment here and I will be at your assistance.